# Testing with Python if table results are null

Tags: python, mysql

```
 query = "SELECT car FROM cars....."

 cursor.execute(query)

 results = cursor.fetchall()
 for row in results:
      if not query:
           print 'No cars available."
      else:
           print row[0]
```

What I'm trying to do is print a message if results are null, or print the results if they have entries. The above code is what I have so far but obviously isn't working. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `query` is a string defined at the top, so `if not query:` will never succeed.  Try testing `row` instead?

Comment: Also, you open your `'No cars available."` with a single quote, but close with a double quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to print "No cars available" when there are no results:

```
 query = "SELECT car FROM cars....."

 cursor.execute(query)

 results = cursor.fetchall()
 if results:
      for row in results:
           print row[0]
 else:
      print 'No cars available.'
```